# Is there a way to create custom tileLayer url in heremaps to use with Leaflet?

Tags: angular, leaflet, maps, heremaps, here-maps-rest

I am using Leaflet maps to load map tiles in my Angular application. The base map I am using is from Here maps.
This is the url I am using. [https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/${style}/{z}/{x}/{y}/512/png8?apiKey=${here.apiKey}&ppi=320](https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/$%7Bstyle%7D/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D/512/png8?apiKey=$%7Bhere.apiKey%7D&ppi=320)
I can change the style variable in the above url for applying predefined styles, but is there a way to create a custom tile url?

I have seen documentation about applying styles at load time using here map renderer, but I want to do it with the leaflet tile url method. Is there a way to generate a custom tile url using Heremaps ?